# Count the number of lines in a file using python and wc -l

Tags: python, linux, cmd

I have this command on linux which I have problem converting into `type`  on Windows:

```
row = run('cat '+'C:/Users/Kyle/Documents/final/VocabCorpus.txt'+" | wc -l").split()[0]
```

For the statement " wc - l"  is for the line count to see how many lines exist. If I were to change it to the following using "type" command, what should it be?

I tried this and it doesnt work.

```
 row = run('type '+'C:/Users/Kyle/Documents/final/VocabCorpus.txt'+" | wc -l").split()[0]
```

The run command is below:

```
def run(command):
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    return output
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: What is the run method? And `wc` isn't a native windows binary

Comment: This statement is to find the number of rows from the vocabulary file and to print it out. Yes I was wondering if there is an equivalent for this statement as this is run in linux. Thanks

Comment: If it is ran in linux, why are you giving it a Windows filesystem path?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am correct but I was told the code can be run on Python for Mac and I tried in for Python for Win, I changed a little but it was not able to run.

Comment: Obviously, because `wc` isn't a command in windows. You should really try not to use OS specific functions if you don't have to and the functions exist in the standard python library to do the same thing (as I've shown in my answer)

Comment: Sorry you are right, there is a run command, it is:

Comment: def run(command):
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    return output

Comment: Once again, the default shell on a Windows computer is `cmd` if you type `wc` in the `cmd` you'll get command not found. You haven't shown your error, but I can guarantee you that that is the problem

Comment: I tried the solution and deleted the line. It provides error as well and I am not sure what to do now.

Comment: What error? Can you please update your question with that information?

Comment: Its more of a logic error, I have found the problem. Thank you very much for your help:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to count the number of lines in a file? Why can't you do that in pure python?

Something like this?

```
with open('C:/Users/Kyle/Documents/final/VocabCorpus.txt') as f:
    row = len(f.readlines())
```

Comment: A slightly better version is ``sum(1 for line in f)``, which consumes less memory: ``f.readlines()`` reads the whole file while iterating over ``f`` yields only one line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `wc` counts `\n` symbols in your file ([proof](https://superuser.com/questions/617049/how-does-wc-l-work)). If you have big files and want to save some memory, you'd better read it by chunks to have O(1) memory consumption:

```
CHUNK_SIZE = 4096

def wc_l(filepath):
    nlines = 0
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            chunk = f.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
            if not chunk:
                break
            nlines += sum(1 for char in chunks if char == '\n')
    return nlines
```